# Why should I use a pull up/down resistor for a GPIO output pin?

Tags: gpio, push-pull

I know there are lots of similar questions and read them, but I need a simpler and clearer answer.

I understand why and how to use a pull up/down resistor when using a button (GPIO input). But while configuring a GPIO pin which will be connected to an LED, what is the use of these settings?

I tried `no pull-up and pull-down` and `pull-up` for example, but I could not see a difference in the implementation.

I am using STM32F407-DISC.

Comment: Read the answer to this post.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156930/stm32-understanding-gpio-settings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pull up/down is only effective in Input or Open Drain configuration.
When set as output there is always an output MOSFET active, the pull up/down is then wasting energy.

The exception is open drain mode, this disables the P-MOS, then pull-up can be useful again.

[image: Figure 25. Basic structure of a five-volt tolerant I/O port bit]

Comment: But the raising edge will be quite slow with the internal (on chip) pull-up resistor(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes. It's ~40 kOhm. But if it's all you've got then it's at least something to keep the pin in a defined state.